Finding a unitary transformation to swap the control bit
Suppose we have a controlled-$U$ gate for some unitary $U$. The convention is that the control-bit is the first bit. I'm interested in finding unitary $V$ so $V^{\otimes 2}(cU)V^{\otimes 2}$ is the "inverted" controlled-$U$. i.e. where the control bit is now the second bit instead. How can we do this in general? I'm more asking for the logic behind how we can go about doing this, not for an explicit solution. Is there a general procedure?
For instance, the Hadamard gate works for controlled-$X$ and the identity works for controlled-$Z$. What about controlled-$Y$?

Unitaries $U$ are diagonalisable. That means there exists a unitary $V$ such that $VUV^\dagger=P$, where $P$ is a phase gate (diagonal matrix). This means that we can think of controlled-$U$ as the circuit

The controlled-$\phi$ phase gate is symmetric (it doesn't matter which you interpret as control or target). This means that we can then just apply

to create controlled-$U$ acting in the opposite direction.
If you're actually going to demand that $V=V^\dagger$ (as in the question), that's potentially going to limit the choice of $U$ still further: if we think of $V=e^{i\theta \vec{n}\cdot\vec{\sigma}}$ then achieving $V=V^\dagger$ up to a global phase requires either $\theta=0$ (i.e. $U$ is a phase gate and controlled-$U$ is already symmetric) or $\theta=\pi/2$. I think the condition is something like $U$ should not have components of both $X$ and $Y$ in its Pauli decomposition. So, for example, a unitary
$$
U=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & e^{-i\pi/4} \\ e^{i\pi/4} & 0 \end{bmatrix}
$$
has a
$$
V=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix}
1 & e^{-5i\pi/4}\\
-1 &e^{-5i\pi/4}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which certainly does not satisfy $V=V^\dagger$.

Given a 2 qubit controlled unitary $U$, one generally expresses it as $$|0\rangle\langle0|\otimes I +  |1\rangle\langle1|\otimes P,$$ where in this example $P$ can be any unitary operator.
In your question, you about swapping the control bit for $C_{Y}$, which is achieved via $$(I\otimes H)(I\otimes S^{\dagger})(|0\rangle\langle0|\otimes I +  |1\rangle\langle1|\otimes Y)(I\otimes S)(I\otimes H)=|0\rangle\langle0|\otimes I +  |1\rangle\langle1|\otimes X$$
This works as $SXS^{\dagger}=Y$. From here, you can just apply $H$ to map it to the $C_{Z}$, which you can swap to the control on the second qubit, and then from here, you can apply the inverse of the original unitary operation to regain the original unitary.
In general, it works as follows:

Map the operation to the $C_{Z}$ via an series of unitary rotations on the second qubit.
Take this as the $C_{Z}$ on the first qubit, instead of the second.
Apply the inverse of the previous operation to the first qubit to take the $C_{Z}$ to the original gate, as this will map $Z$ to the original unitary.


What's S? The swap gate?

S is the phase gate $$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\
0 & i
\end{bmatrix}$$
